# BATCH script: Cannot get modified date for file in nested loop

Tags: date, batch-file

I am having trouble getting the date modified for my file from within a nested loop.

I am running this batch script:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
net use S: \\devfs\edcsrc\epoletto\campusanyware

SET CLIENTS= DEMO

FOR %%a in (%CLIENTS%) DO (

    S:
    CD AD
    FOR %%B in (*.cbl) DO (
        set file=%%B
        echo !file!
        for %%c in (!file!) do (echo %%~ta))

)
pause
net use S: /delete /Y
ECHO.
```

Here is my output:

```
The command completed successfully.

ad1.cbl
ECHO is off.
ad2.cbl
ECHO is off.
ad3.cbl
ECHO is off.
Press any key to continue . . .
```

All of my file names are correct, but when the script goes into the the third FOR loop (for %%c in (!file!) do (echo %%~ta))), I cannot get the date/time modified for my file.

As a proof of concept, I tried this same logic from the command line from within the directory:

```
for %B in (*.cbl) DO (for %a in (%B) do echo %~ta)
```

And my output from that command was (including initial command):

```
V:\>for %B in (*.cbl) DO (for %a in (%B) do echo %~ta)

V:\>(for %a in (ad1.cbl) do echo %~ta )

V:\>echo 05/02/2017 11:32 AM
05/02/2017 11:32 AM

V:\>(for %a in (ad2.cbl) do echo %~ta )

V:\>echo 04/18/2017 02:04 PM
04/18/2017 02:04 PM

V:\>(for %a in (ad3.cbl) do echo %~ta )

V:\>echo 04/27/2017 11:46 AM
04/27/2017 11:46 AM
```

I'm confused as to why I can't get these dates from within my script. My ultimate goal is to check the date for each file and then execute another command dependent on that date.  Right now I'm just trying to verify I can get the date using echo. Any suggestions are appreciated!

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
        for %%c in (!file!) do (echo %%~ta))
```

use

```
        for %%c in (!file!) do (echo %%~tc))
```

because you want the modified time of `%%c`, not of `%%a`.

:)